# Firebase AB Testing: What happens to existing variants when running the same experiment again with different number of variants?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I have an A/B testing experiment running with 3 variants Control, Var A and Var B at 33.3% distribution for each. Now I want to stop that experiment and run it again with just 2 variants: Control and Var B. That way they will have 50% distribution for each. My question is: will the 33.3% of users who got variant B during the first run of the same experiment get a different variant when I run this experiment again (by keeping the same remote config parameter name)  with just 2 variants (Control and Var B)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you create a new A/B test (even if it's a duplicate of a previous one), you're essentially "re-rolling" all of your users to determine what variant they go into.